# How to create a array with the values in the row in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

In my app, I have a database with values like name, number, mark.
I can recruit the values from the db as each array for name, number and mark.
I want to get the values of each person
Consider I have 3 students.

```
nameArray=(a,b,c);
numberArray=(1,2,3);
markArray=(25,50,75);
```

Now I want to get separate the value for each student, I needed

```
stud1=(a,1,25);
stud2=(b,2,50);
stud3=(c,3,75);
```

I couldnt get any idea for this, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are those values, in the database, all connected to a student? I.e. Do you have some way of identifying a student, like a student ID, for example? Or, are you relying on the sequence of those values? Are those bits of data in 3 separate tables?

Comment: in my table there are three columns(name, number,marks), with the above values

Comment: Ok thanks; so each row corresponds to a student. I assume that you're doing a select on each of the columns, individually, to get those 3 arrays? E.g. Select Name From ...

Comment: ya, i dont want to select from column, i want to select according to the row

Comment: That's your answer: do a select giving you all the values for each row, and use the results to create a collection of students. I assume you have a class of some kind to represent a student? In your code?

Comment: What database are you using? Post the code you've written so far to retrieve (recruit) the values for name, number and marks.

Comment: @Chandru you can read nsarry by index in order.means student1=nameArray=(index1),;
numberArray(index1));
markArray(index1); for next stu next index......

Comment: i am using sqlite, and select operation for recruiting the values @GavinHope

Comment: @square, can u please elaborate

Comment: what you want stud1=(a,1,25); in this value @Chandru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, if you want to do a select statement that takes all the relevant data for a student, check out one or both of these guides. They're not the most current but the have what you need:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app

This example starts off with a `FailedBankInfo` object, which would match up with your `Student`. Note that they have the following method to create one of these objects using the values from the database:

```
- (id)initWithUniqueId:(int)uniqueId name:(NSString *)name city:(NSString *)city 
    state:(NSString *)state
```

The tutorial shows you how to get those values and to loop through the results.

Here's a second tutorial:

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

In this one, the example at the start is an `Animal` object. A number of `Animal`s are created from values in the database, similar to your `Student`. The `Animal` class looks like this:

```
@interface Animal : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    NSString *description;
    NSString *imageURL;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageURL;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u;

@end
```

Those tutorials should get you going.

For additional information, **@square** was suggesting the following...

If you can rely on the sequence of the values in the three arrays, and by that I mean, if the values at index 3 in each of the arrays corresponds to the same student, you could do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.count; i++) {
    Student* student = [[Student alloc] initWithName:nameArray[i] number:numberArray[i] mark:markArray[i]];
    [theStudents addObject:student];
}
```

The above relies on you having a class called `Student` with an `init` taking name, number and mark. And a mutable array called `theStudents`.

Comment: nice explanation @Gavin Hope

Comment: No problem. The feedback from other users suggests you should add more clarity to your question... It's worth considering. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

like this you can try, i dint get ,where you want to pass stud1=(a,1,25); this value, for i=0 you will get stud1=(a,1,25);

```
NSArray  *name1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",nil];
    NSArray  *num2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
    NSArray  *marks3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"341",@"452",@"353",nil];

    for (int i=0;i<[name1 count]; i++) {

        NSLog(@"%@",[name1 objectAtIndex:i ]);
         NSLog(@"%@",[num2 objectAtIndex:i ]);
         NSLog(@"%@",[marks3 objectAtIndex:i ]);

        // NSLog(@"%@",[obj1 objectAtIndex:i ]);
        // store or display where you want
```